# What is a react callback in scalajs-react?

Tags: reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

[Here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/FP.md) it is written:

> Included is a type CallbackTo[A] which captures effects designated for
>   use in React callbacks.

What is a React callback in this context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, just the normal meaning of callback - a function that is called in response to an event. So for example in a [React Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) there are many functions like `componentDidMount` that are called at different stages in the lifecycle of the component. In scalajs-react these are implemented as functions that return a `CallbackTo[Unit]`, which can also be written as `Callback` due to a type alias. For example when adding a `componentDidMount` callback to a `ReactComponentB`, we use `def componentDidMount(f: DuringCallbackM[P, S, B, N] => Callback): ReactComponentB[P, S, B, N]`.

In javascript a component is expected to just immediately run any side-effects of the event, in the `componentDidMount` function (or the other callbacks). In scalajs-react, the component instead wraps these effects in a `Callback`, and returns that. This allows for the scalajs-react system to delay actual execution of the code in the `Callback` - this is done later by calling `runNow()`. This also means that `Callbacks` are combined using `map`, `flatMap`, `>>` etc. They will not run unless `runNow()` is eventually called, so if you are not returning a `Callback` to some other code to execute later, just creating it will do nothing.

There's [much more about Callback in the docs](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/CALLBACK.md).